# access nested JSON object with random or unknown name on karate framework

Tags: arrays, json, validation, karate

I have this piece of JSON response

```
"A": {
"RandomName01": {
    "B": "BOS",
    "C": {
        "RandomName02": {
            "D": "32",
            "E": "ABC",
            "F": "DEF"
        }
    },
    "G": "GHI"
}
```

I need to extract value of D from it, having two RandomName tags on the way.
I can't find anything in documentation related to handling unknown names. I tried using [], *, [0], .. etc but I failed.

For example:

- def value = response.A..C..D
- def value = response[0].C[0].D

etc...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for help. Your answer has made me try jsonPath in karate

This has made a trick:

```
* def value = karate.jsonPath(response, "$..D")
```

To try jsonPath I used:
http://jsonpath.com/

For jsonPath expressions I used:
https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work,

```
* def value = response..["D"]
```

you can deepscan any key using `..` operator

karate uses jsonpath for JSON manipulation.

Please refer [Json path operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) for more useful information.